# Microsoftgraph Which Ids to remove license?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to remove a license from a user using the microsoft graph API.  I am currently using graph explorer to experiment with this.

I have not found much information here regarding microsoftgraph.  I find the microsoft documentation and examples unclear on this point.

Here is the data I have to work with. [graph explorer snip_one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opdJ1.png) I have tried option A)

When I post to the assignLicense endpoint, I get this error message, and I find little information via google/SO about this.  [graph explorer snip_two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD725.png)  Specifically, I find little about

"Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'"

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Guid'. See the inner exception for more details.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "7e63fcf2-8fce-4a5c-9f40-3348fba1fb13",
            "date": "2019-12-05T01:37:14"
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, with more experimentation, the skuID was what was needed in the removedLicenses list

Answer (score 0):

It's the GUID here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference

Note there's a link to the latest version in CSV file format.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30991896)